# Send mail from GCLOUD to other email(gmail,yahoo). Like email verification link, subscription confirmation

Tags: email, cloud, jakarta-mail, google-compute-engine, gcloud-java

```
     import java.util.*;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  
import javax.activation.*;  

public class SendEmail  
{  
 public static void main(String [] args){  
      String to = "gourab.p17@gmail.com";

      String from = "gp@sharenodes.com";
      String host = "localhost";//or IP address  


      Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  


      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

      try{  
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
         message.setSubject("Ping");  
         message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  

         // Send message  
         Transport.send(message);  
         System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  

      }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}  
   }  
}
```

I dont want to go for sendgrid/google-email-api/mailgun
I have mapped DNS-A(host) @ 23.236.49.96    600 seconds   sharenodes.com
But not able to send mail. Tried  properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "2525");
But no mail received neither error. For port 25, 465, 587 it throws error as google has blocked these ports

Comment: **GCLOUD compute engine**

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. With that said, you can set up your own email server on any of the ports not blocked by Compute Engine or you can use partner services like SendGrid, Mailgun, or using Google Apps. The information is documented on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/)

Comment: I have set my own smtp postfix and updated mx record. When I sendmail . in var/log/mail.log its shows mail send. But I didnt receive any mail on gmail